# updating the Child Component based on search results in react-hooks functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have `react-App` with redux using `react-hooks` functional components, it renders the list of tutors in **child component** correctly. i have added a search box in it and `handlchange` function to update the list component(child compenent). the `handlechange` function works fine and assign the `newlist` to `filtered` variable in side the `handlechange function` body however the value of `filtered` outside the `handlechange` function remains **unchanged**.so the  updated filtered variable not assigned to `TutorList Component`.
the `Tutors.jsx` Component is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useParams, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import TutorList from "./TutorList";
import * as actions from "../_actions/tutorActions";
import { TextField, Button, FormControl, } from "@material-ui/core";

const initialFieldValues = {
  search: ""
}

const Tutors = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues)

  let history = useHistory()
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // getting of tutorlist
  let tutor = useSelector(state => state.tutor.list);
  // sorting of tutors on date
  let tutorList = tutor.sort((a, b) => b.updatedOn.localeCompare(a.updatedOn));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.fetchAll())
  }, [])

  console.log("tutorList:", tutorList)

  // Variable to hold the filtered list before putting into state

  let newList = [];
  let filtered = tutorList;
  //when filter changes from '' to something filtered should be updated with newlist

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    const fieldValue = { [name]: value }
    setValues({
      ...values,
      ...fieldValue
    })

    // If the search bar isn't empty
    if (values.search !== "") {
      // Use .filter() to determine which items should be displayed
      // based on the search terms
      newList = tutorList.filter(item => {
        // change current item to lowercase
        const lc = item.fullName.toLowerCase();
        // change search term to lowercase
        const filter = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        console.log("filter", filter);
        // check to see if the current list item includes the search term
        // If it does, it will be added to newList. Using lowercase eliminates
        // issues with capitalization in search terms and search content
        return lc.includes(filter);
      });
    } else {
      newList = tutorList;
    }
    console.log("newList:", newList)//shows correct list
    filtered = newList
    console.log("filtered:", filtered)//shows correct value
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <TextField
        name="search"
        variant="outlined"
        label="Search Tutor"
        paceholder="search tutor..."
        value={values.search}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <TutorList
        tutorList={filtered}

      />

      <Button onClick={() => history.goBack()}
        size="small" variant="contained" color="secondary">
        back
       </Button>
    </div>
  );

}

export default Tutors;
```

the `TutorList` Component should Show the newList based on filter entered in search field. any one help to workaround or better solution .thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to update newList, filtered from handleChange. React doesn't work this way. You won't get a rerender. The only thing you should do in your handleChange is setValue

```js
const [textInputValue, setTextInputValue] = useState('');
    function handleChange(e) {
        setTextInputValue(e.target.value);
    }
```

then do all the sorting based on

```js
let tutor = useSelector(state => state.tutor.list)
// and textInputValue
```

Also there's no need to store filtered values in state.

Answer (score 0):

create a new state for

```
const Tutors =(props)=> {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues)
    const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(null)
```

inside of `handleChange()` function set the `filtered` with that of filtered element:

```js
 function handleChange(e){
       //........

      console.log("newList:",newList)//shows correct list
      //filtered=newList  <= instead of this 
      setFiltered(newList) // <= do this
      console.log("filtered:",filtered)//shows correct value
    }
```

The final code should look like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import TutorList from "./TutorList";
import * as actions from "../_actions/tutorActions";
import { TextField, Button, FormControl } from "@material-ui/core";

const initialFieldValues = {
  search: "",
};

const Tutors = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialFieldValues);
  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(null);

  let history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // getting of tutorlist
  let tutor = useSelector((state) => state.tutor.list);
  // sorting of tutors on date
  let tutorList = tutor.sort((a, b) => b.updatedOn.localeCompare(a.updatedOn));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.fetchAll());
  }, []);

  console.log("tutorList:", tutorList);

  // Variable to hold the filtered list before putting into state

  let newList = [];
  let filtered = tutorList;
  //when filter changes from '' to something filtered should be updated with newlist

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const fieldValue = { [name]: value };
    setValues({
      ...values,
      ...fieldValue,
    });

    // If the search bar isn't empty
    if (values.search !== "") {
      // Use .filter() to determine which items should be displayed
      // based on the search terms
      newList = tutorList.filter((item) => {
        // change current item to lowercase
        const lc = item.fullName.toLowerCase();
        // change search term to lowercase
        const filter = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        console.log("filter", filter);
        // check to see if the current list item includes the search term
        // If it does, it will be added to newList. Using lowercase eliminates
        // issues with capitalization in search terms and search content
        return lc.includes(filter);
      });
    } else {
      newList = tutorList;
    }
    console.log("newList:", newList); //shows correct list
    setFiltered(newList); // update filtered state
    console.log("filtered:", filtered); //shows correct value
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <TextField
        name="search"
        variant="outlined"
        label="Search Tutor"
        paceholder="search tutor..."
        value={values.search}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      {filtered && <TutorList tutorList={filtered} />}

      <Button
        onClick={() => history.goBack()}
        size="small"
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
      >
        back
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tutors;
```

Comment: thanks for helping. i have tried this, as i have used pagination on tutorList it does not work due to undefined length of null.if i use array [] instead of null in `const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(null);` it does not render first time .it shows empty list.

Comment: just use conditional rendering. ```{filtered && <TutorList tutorList={filtered} />}```